# How can I change a button's emoji without resetting the component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to change button's current emoji to a new one like this:

```
// Initializing button
const row = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('play_pause')
            .setEmoji('⏸')
            .setStyle('PRIMARY')
    )
// Button was sent to Discord
await message.channel.send({
                components: [row]
            });
// Changing content of a button
row.components[0].setEmoji('▶');
```

But in the Discord nothing changes.
When I call console log, I get this:

```
MessageButton {
  type: 'BUTTON',
  label: null,
  customId: 'play_pause',
  style: 'PRIMARY',
  emoji: { animated: false, name: '▶', id: null },
  url: null,
  disabled: false
}
```

So as I get it, I need to resend the button for it to change.
But can I somehow change the content without resending it?

Comment: Tried using interaction.edit, not working, although console.log is saying emoji has changed
i.message.edit(playButton.setEmoji('⏸'));

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to edit any of a `<MessageButton>`'s properties without re-setting a `<MessageActionRow>`'s components.